# Configuring NLOG with PublishSingleFile option set

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nlog

I am in a corner now and I am not able to resolve this problem to my satisfaction.

The problems is caused by the use of NLOG in the Program.cs file of an ASP.NET Core 3.0
application when the application is published using the flag PublishSingleFile in the
Visual Studio 2019's Publish options dialog with a SelfContained application.

See: [Publishing a single file in NET Core 3.0](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/06/20/publishing-a-single-exe-file-in-net-core-3-0/)

If I enable this option the publish procedure creates a single file that contains
all the required files including the NLOG assembly.
I deploy this standalone executable
along with configurations file like appsettings.json and nlog.config in the site's root
as well the content folder wwwroot.

The problem arises when a request arrives to start the application.
At this point I get an immediate crash at the first line of the main method.
After enabling the stdout.log file I can see the reason.

> Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Failed to load
> NLog LoggingConfiguration. Searched the following locations:
>
> - C:\Windows\TEMP.net\MyAPI\11jsrg2n.1ad\nlog.config
>
> File name: 'nlog.config'    at
> NLog.LogFactory.LoadConfiguration(String configFile, Boolean optional)
> at NLog.LogFactory.LoadConfiguration(String configFile)    at
> NLog.LogManager.LoadConfiguration(String configFile)    at
> NLog.Web.NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog(String configFileName)    at
> MyAPI.Program.Main(String[] args)

It seems like the whole exe is run from a different directory than the site's root folder.

Of course this happens because the first line in my main method tries to initialize the NLOG assembly.

To complete this question this is the code on my program.cs file

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var logger = NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config").GetCurrentClassLogger();
        try
        {
            logger.Info("----------------------------");
            logger.Info("MyAPI Application Start");
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error(ex, "MyAPI stopped on Exception");
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            LogManager.Shutdown();
        }
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
            {
                logging.ClearProviders();
                logging.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Warning);
            })
            .UseNLog()
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

So, thanks to everyone that followed my explanation and here is the question.

These is a way to configure NLOG in the main method (as well in the Startup code) when the application is published using the PublishSingleFile flag?

I forgot to add that if I publish without this settings everything works fine, thus this problem is not a showstopper, but nevertheless I would like to know if
there is a workaround.

Comment: it seems NLog 4.7 has made additional accommodations for PublishSingleFile. see here https://nlog-project.org/2020/03/28/nlog-4-7-has-been-released.html#net-core-single-file-publish

Comment: It seems they have added a workaround for specifying the appropriate log path:
<target type="file" fileName="${basedir:fixtempdir=true}\App.txt" />

Comment: Also: "If wanting to support override of the NLog.config, that has been packaged into the single file (Ex. SingleApp.exe). Then one must rename NLog.config to SingleApp.exe.nlog. Then NLog will prioritize the SingleApp.exe.nlog placed next to the actual SingleApp.exe, but will fallback to SingleApp.exe.nlog in the secret temp folder."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want NLog.config included/embedded in the single-exe-file, then try to specify this in csproj-file:

```
<Content Include="nlog.config">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
  <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
</Content>
```

If you want to have NLog.config to be placed externally/outside the single-exe-file. Then try to explicit specify the process-directory:

```
var processPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
var nlogConfigPath = Path.Combine(processPath, "nlog.config");
var logger = NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog(nlogConfigPath).GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try your solutions, but do they make the nlog.config still editable if I need to fine tune it?. This application is deployed in an hosting environment provided by an ISP that doesn't allow me to reach folders or files outside the root folder. So for example I need to change the target path inside the nlog.config to point to the wwwroot/log relative to the site's root.

Comment: @tpol If you want to modify the `NLog.config` after deployment, then you should NOT have the `NLog.config` included/embedded in the single-exe-file. But instead deploy it side-by-side and use the `processPath`-example.

Comment: The solution using the `processPath` example works. So you have resolved my problem. At this point I am still not sure if I really want to use the single exe approach. Yes I have a lot less files to distribute, but it seems that the startup time is really longer and copying a 100 MB file when I have just a little incremental fixes seems to dwarf all the advantages.

Comment: @tpol You can try and use `<PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>` to reduce the file-size. See also https://www.hanselman.com/blog/MakingATinyNETCore30EntirelySelfcontainedSingleExecutable.aspx